# Emacs equivalent of Vim's word motion and change in-line word

Tags: vim, emacs, editing

In Emacs I can go one word forward and backward by using <kbd>M-f</kbd> and <kbd>M-b</kbd> but if I have to go three words backwards or forward I need to repeat the previous sequence three times which seems inelegant. What is the Emacs equivalent of the word-motion concept in Vim? For example, in Vim I can move forward by two words by issuing `2w` and backwards by issuing `2b` while I am in command mode.

1. What are the equivalent commands in Emacs for moving between words (more than one at a time)?
2. Actually I would like go to particular word and change it also. In Vim I can do this via <kbd>ciw</kbd> (change in-line word). What would be the equivalent command in Emacs?

Comment: Just came across [`change-inner.el`](https://github.com/magnars/change-inner.el) which brings vim's `ci` (and `co`) to Emacs. The package is available from [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) and can be `package-install`ed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `universal-argument`. There are two ways to move 3 words forward:

- <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>M-f</kbd>
- <kbd>C-3</kbd><kbd>M-f</kbd>

But that's usually slower than doing <kbd>M-f</kbd> 3 times. You know you don't have release <kbd>M</kbd>, right?

I do not know what vim's <kbd>civ</kbd> does, but to go to a word just search for it with <kbd>C-s</kbd>. If you like to jump around have a look at [Ace Jump](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AceJump). It works like the follow links feature of browser plugins like vimperator. With it you can jump to lines, word or even chars.

---

Ok, I don't think there is a built-in for that. Maybe this function helps:

```
(defun delete-word-at-point ()
  "Delete word at point."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((p (point))
         (beg (+ p   (skip-syntax-backward "w_")))
         (end (+ beg (skip-syntax-forward  "w_"))))
    (kill-region beg end)))
```

Put it in your `~/.emacs` and bind to where you would like it. Maybe <kbd>M-.</kbd>:

```
(global-set-key (read-kbd-macro "M-.") 'delete-word-at-point)
```

Comment: `ciw` is "change inner word", which erases the word under the cursor and puts you into insert mode to type a new one.

Comment: I'd rather do `backwards-word`, then `kill-word` (less instructions). Also, probably, you don't want to bind to `M-.` because it's usually for moving to the declaration of the thing you are looking at. Maybe use `M-r` - that's the command I never find any use for.